# Git, having 1 file content different in local and remote

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, version-control, repository

Ok, so I'm trying to have 2 versions of a config file :

Locally, on my computer, I'd like to have config.js :

```
angular.module('app')
  .constant('config', {
    backendBaseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/catalog'
  });
```

And on the git repo used to pull and deploy on a server, I'd like to have in config.js :

```
angular.module('app')
  .constant('config', {
    backendBaseUrl: '/api/catalog'
  });
```

I'm using IntelliJ in order to commit/push with `Ctrl+K` & `Ctrl+Shift+k`.

So I tried to make the file like I want on the git repo, push it, and then rename it and not adding it to git. But the file got deleted from the git repo after the last push.

I also tried to push it and then add its path to the `.gitignore` before modifying it. (Not sure I did that right though)

It must not be that complicated  to achieve with a bit of knowledge in git.

Comment: Totally not clear what you want. "So I tried to make the file like I want on the git repo, push it, and then rename it and not adding it to git. But the file got deleted from the git repo after the last push."  adding file, pushing it, not adding ti to git?

Comment: Well I pushed the file, I modified it and renamed it so It won't erase the one I just pushed. But it did delete it in the repo. (Since it doesn't exist anymore locally after the renaming)

Comment: How did you renamed the file? `git mv`? and the file is in the repo even if you deleted it. its just not in the current snapshot

Comment: I just renamed it using the IDE GUI. In the end I just want one file not to be pushed again after being pushed once even if I modify it

Comment: I wrote you a full answer below with several options. You can use the `assume-unchanged` which will tell git to ignore any changes made to this file, and with the `git add -p` you can ad only parts of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few things which you can do.

several options:

#### `.gitignore`

Add the file to `.gitignore` file- so git will ignore it from now on.
**Note**: In your case since you have already added the file you will have to use the `assume-unchanged`

```
# .gitignore content
robots.txt
```

---

#### `assume-unchanged`

Use this flag to mark your local changes as unchanged so git will not track any changes including your file delete.

#### To temporarily ignore changes in a certain file, run:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

#### When you want to track changes again:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

---

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]

---

#### `git add -p`

Add the desired part per branch (add patch)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really understand the part with the `git add -p` and its screenshot but I got the other one with the `assume-unchanged` flag.
However, how the fact that I already added the file in `.gitignore` once makes it necessary to use this flag ? I thought adding the file path in `.gitignore` would be enough

Comment: Once you add file to git (git add ) git starts to track it form this point on. so you have to "tell" git not to track it form now on, That's what the assume-unchanged do.

Comment: That is not what assume-unchanged does - see documentation for update-index for accurate description: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

Answer (score 1):

`git update-index --skip-worktree <path_to_file>` is exactly what you need.

From git documentation:

> When reading an entry, if it is marked as skip-worktree, then Git pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the index version instead

Do not confuse `--skip-worktree` with `--assume-unchanged`. 
When you set the latest flag you promise git not to do any changes.

Git manual is not very clear about it, so the best explanation I've found [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/246350) (from Junio Hamano, git maintainer):

> Assume-unchanged should not be abused for an ignore mechanism. It is "I know my filesystem operations are slow. I'll promise Git that I won't change these paths by making them with that bit---that way, Git does not have to check if I changed things in there every time I ask for 'git status' output". It does not mean anything other than that. Especially, it is not a promise by Git that Git will always consider these paths are unmodified---if Git can determine a path that is marked as assume-unchanged has changed without incurring extra lstat(2) cost, it reserves the right to report that the path has been modified (as a result, "git commit -a" is free to commit that change)